# Default resource bundle not picked up on production server

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, internationalization

Here is my faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
    <application>
        <message-bundle>messages</message-bundle>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>fr</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>messages</base-name>
            <var>messages</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

Here are the resource bundles

- `src/main/resources/messages.properties` -> `hello=bonjour`
- `src/main/resources/messages_en.properties` -> `hello=hello`

On the JSF page `#{view.locale}` displays `fr_FR`, however `#{messages['hello']}` displays `hello` where `bonjour` was expected.

When the JBoss7 is run on development machine, the internationalization works. `bonjour` is displayed properly. When I copy the whole JBoss server, including its deployements, on the production machine, internationalization does not work.

Both machines run Windows 8.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? What's the incoming `Accept-Language` request header? What if you rename `messages.properties` to `messages_fr.properties` and then add an empty `messages.properties`?

Comment: JSF2.0. Moving default labels to message_fr works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help BalusC :-)

Comment: "JSF 2.0" is just a spec version. I was asking for the impl (Mojarra or MyFaces) and its version (2.0.x whereby x is of major interest).